# android sdk - required for building and installing your app on android- versions found: n/a- version supported: 33.0.0?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am installing react-native but getting this error. This error is of Android SDK not found when I run npx react-native doctor command.
[image]

I have followed exact the same steps written in react-native official doc but still getting the error. I have tried many solutions already discussed of adding the cmdtools path to environment variables but I have added cmdtools/latest/bin, platform tools, tools, emulator all these paths to the system and user variables but still not able to resolve it. Then I uninstalled android studio and again installed SDK 34 and 33 as well as hypervision and HAXM along with pixel 4a emulator. But I am not able to run after doing all this.

Answer (score 3):

Install an older version of cmdtools
and change cmdtools path:

```
dtools/latest/bin`
```

by

```
cmdtools/{your new version}/bin
```

For example

```
/cmdline-tools/8.0/bin
```

that worked for me.

Comment: Still getting the same thing
version found: N/A